# Add space between string array using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am working in angularjs project,

```
var res = ["Art","Logic","Science"];
$scope.output = res;
```

Result is displayed as

> Art,Logic,Science

I need the result as -

> Art, Logic, Science

Have to add space between each string array value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `join()` method to achieve this.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('SpaceCntrl', function($scope) {
  var result = ["Art", "Logic", "Science"];
  $scope.res = result.join(', ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="SpaceCntrl">
    <span ng-bind="res"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do it:

```
$scope.output = res.join(', ');
```

Using [Array.propotype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 0):

Joining the array will do it :)

```
var res = ["Art","Logic","Science"];
$scope.output = res.join(', ');
```